# Can a player character increase stats?

Tags: character-advancement, call-of-cthulhu, call-of-cthulhu-7e

I'm a new GM. With friends, we had two sessions, and after each of them, I've let them roll for skills increase. But recently one of them asked if he should roll for STR because his character is weak and despite that managed to force doors and a chest.

My first thought was "It's logical" but later I started to think about other stats, like "You can't simply increase your character Size", so I've said that I don't really know and I'd try to find out before next meeting.

I've found similar questions about Power, but it didn't help with my doubt.

So should I let him try to increase this or other stats?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no "advancement system" when it comes to attributes, but ageing modifies them, sometimes significantly. It's usually an EDU check which could raise it of 1d10, coupled with some automatic loss (although turning 20 lets the character gain 5 points divided among STR and SIZ).

All of this is explained page 98 of the Core Rulebook (7th ed).

Answer (score 2):

## RAW, No there is no way to increase Stats (except POW)

There is no rule to cover increasing base Character Stats in a way that is consistent with Skill improvement system.

If you want to do this, you will need to use a homebrew solution: possibly spending downtime in the gym can provide a temporary benefit to Strength, for example.

As an aside, it is worth noting that "Character Development" in Call of Cthulhu is very weak. Skills only increase marginally over time and Sanity is guaranteed to diminish. I usually warn my players that, unlike most other RPGs, Characters in CoC do not improve and, in fact, they will significantly decline over time. As they lose more and more Sanity, they will literally go mad, and many Mythos monsters have damaging effects that are permanent.

Answer (score 1):

While there is no direct way(Except POW) there are spells that convert POW into different attributes. As a result an investigator who is willing to risk their sanity can in theory increase their attributes.